# Customize cordova inapp browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I wish to change the text and colour of the done link on the cordova inapp browser. My project is built with ionic and cordova and I made changes in the /plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m file but nothing happened.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about posting the changes you made? The text can be changed from javascript

Comment: Can you let me know where I can add the javascript to do so. I am using ionic with angular and can;'t figure out where to put the code

Comment: when you create the inAppBrowser with window.open, use the closebuttoncaption option (it's iOS only)

Comment: The window is being opened with ionic authWithOAuthPopup. Is there way I can add this into that call?

Comment: Can you edit your question and start from the beginning, give more details and provide code and screenshots? Your comments don't make sense with your question

Comment: I have an ionic app which calls a popup window when a user tries to login with twitter. This opens up the cordova inAppBrowser automatically. there is no code to call the window to open. I wish to customize the "done" button and the colour of it, but the changes I have done within the plugin doesnt make any effect

Comment: Check my answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/38350462/6449750

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this. I was able to change the color.

In your `CDVInAppBrowser.m` file, you can edit following line:

```
self.closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0 / 255.0 green:136.0 / 255.0 blue:0.0 / 250.0 alpha:1];
```

If you also want to change the color of the next/previous arrow add following lines:

```
self.backButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.forwardButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Resulting in this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPYPQ.png)

Comment: is it possible to authenticate when we trigger in inAppbrowser web page, we have requirement to authenticate if user logged in actual mobile app, so that similar credentials to validate the web application pages.