# How to Create Custom Inapp Browser?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Hi I want to add Some buttons over the inAppbrowser in my android application how to add here is my code

```
$scope.customInappbrowser = function() {

    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.co.in', '_blank', options)
          .then(function(event) {
            // success
          })
          .catch(function(event) {
            // error
          });

       // window.open(v, "_system", "location=yes");
    }
$scope.customInappbrowser();
```

Comment: You will have to make those changes in plugin's native files.

Comment: Is there any examples available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following plugin that is already modified.
[cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser). You can refer its code for reference.
Regards.

Comment: Usefull Plugin Thanks